# How to use CURL via a proxy URL It's possible?

Tags: php, curl

Hello I am playing with a proxy server in php
I'm doing

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

where `$proxy` has as value

```
miurl.com/proxy.php
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
If I put the ip address to dry it works but not with URL
Is there any way to make it work but with URL?

Additional notes i am using this proxy server in php

```
https://github.com/zounar/php-proxy
```

Comment: To be clear, the proxy works with the IP address and not the domain name when a URL is used (same URL, just swapping IP for host), or are we talking about accessing the proxy in different ways?

Comment: it happens that I have the proxy in the php server
Is there any way to put it as a URL?

Comment: @Club that script is not a normal HTTP proxy. Based on the documentation, you can't use it with `CURLOPT_PROXY`. Instead it seems you're required to change the normal request url to the proxy endpoint and add custom headers with the real endpoint you're trying to reach.

Comment: interesting I'm going to change the script PHP proxy server
I'm going to try another